# javascript expand exponential

Tags: javascript, math, exponential

Found this function here

http://jsfromhell.com/string/expand-exponential

```
String.prototype.expandExponential = function(){
return this.replace(/^([+-])?(\d+).?(\d*)[eE]([-+]?\d+)$/, function(x, s, n, f, c){
    var l = +c < 0, i = n.length + +c, x = (l ? n : f).length,
    c = ((c = Math.abs(c)) >= x ? c - x + l : 0),
    z = (new Array(c + 1)).join("0"), r = n + f;
    return (s || "") + (l ? r = z + r : r += z).substr(0, i += l ? z.length : 0) + (i < r.length ? "." + r.substr(i) : "");
});
};
```

I sort of get the replace part, but I'm lost when I see the function(x,s,n,f,c) part. What am I missing?

Can someone help me break this down into more understandable components?

Comment: [MDN documentation for "replace"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)

Comment: These are just argument names, arbitrary and obfuscated/minified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter)

Basically, `x` is the matched substring. `s` corresponds to the part that was matched by the first pair of parentheses (`([+-])`), `n` corresponds to the part matched by the second parentheses (`(\d+)`), and so on.

The matched string is replaced by the value returned by this function.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a function as the second parameter of a `replace()` call.

The parameter list ([from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)):

- the matches substring - in your case `x`
- the n parenthesized submatch strings - in your case 2: `s` and `n`
- offset of the matched substring - in your case `f`
- the total string - in your case `c`